# Detox Jest Could not resolve a module for a custom reporter

Tags: react-native, jestjs, detox

I just upgraded my Detox from ^18.6.2 to ^20.11.3 and Jest from ^26.6.3 to ^29.
Followed the migration [docs](https://wix.github.io/Detox/docs/guide/migration). `detox build` works well however when I try to run `detox test` I get the error below

```
Error: Could not resolve a module for a custom reporter.
  Module name: detox/runners/jest/reporter
    at /<path>/node_modules/jest-config/build/normalize.js:426:15
```

My config.js file is as below:

```
module.exports = {
  maxWorkers: 1,
  testTimeout: 120000,
  rootDir: "..",
  testMatch: ["<rootDir>/e2e/**/*.e2e.js"],
  verbose: true,
  reporters: ["detox/runners/jest/reporter"],
  globalSetup: "detox/runners/jest/globalSetup",
  globalTeardown: "detox/runners/jest/globalTeardown",
  testEnvironment: "detox/runners/jest/testEnvironment",
};
```

Node `14.17.6` npm `6.14.15`, also tried with a higher node version(20.5.0) and that didn't work either